# Why i get this error when i use dev express file upload in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, iis, devexpress

I'm using the devexpress file upload,and when run that web form appliaction in my local machine,every thing is ok,but when publish that web site on the my server i get this error:
[image]

what happen?thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check this box. Your problem is solved.
[image]

Comment: thanks your for answer and pay attention to my problem.